# Lack of consistency in python, completely contradictory behaviour of defined variables before function

Tags: python, function, definition

I'm losing my mind because my code is doing completely contradictory action.
I'm defining `packet_counts` as Counter() before defining function `custom_action` and there is no problem. When I try to define `test1` as int exactly the same way as `packet_counts` it's saying that `test1` inside `custom_action` is undefined.
What a lack of consistency.
Could you guys explain to me what is wrong?

I tried with `global` with the same result. I cannot define `test1` inside function because it has to collect size of captured packets using scapy, and if I'd do so, it would reset each time when it's called.

```
from collections import Counter

test1=0
packet_counts = Counter()
def custom_action(packet):
    key = tuple(sorted([packet[0][1].src, packet[0][1].dst]))
    packet_counts.update([key])
    packetSize = len(packet)
    test1 += packetSize              #here occurs error that test1 is undefined...
```

Comment: Its because you assign to the variable within the function. Variable scope is tricky in python. Add `nonlocal test1` to the top of your function.

Comment: You need to use the global keyword before playing with test1. I.e global test1 .... then test1 += packetSize. I'm not sure why this is but possibly variables assigned to objects have some precedence behind the scenes that this is taken care of.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse  You mean before of my funtion? i tried with `global` and `nonlocal ` but now it says `invalid syntax`

Comment: It may help you to read about [variable scope](https://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html) in python.

Comment: Also, can you not just pass `test1` as a paramater?

Comment: @KyleJ It is not about precedence it is about that variables in Python are references to objects. There is no problem on calling methods of `Counter()` object. You can't reassign them out of scope

Comment: Btw this should be a hint that what you are doing is bad practice. As Jammy noted you should pass needed variables to methods or functions. You should not work with global or nonlocal scopes.

Comment: as you see, even adding global(I mentioned it in original post) doesn't help: https://imgur.com/sN3NYz5 
And the thing is that I cannot pass it to this function, because it's scapy's function

Comment: @JędrzejKieruj Then please provide a minimal complete and verifiable example that we can run. Get it to fail without using any modules (such as scipy) and post that minimal code in your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any name *assigned* in a function is implicitly local; if you only read from a name, it will read from the nearest scope containing the variable.

```
test1 += packetSize
```

is both reading and assigning, making `test1` local, but since it wasn't assigned a value beforehand, you get an `UnboundLocalError` (because you effectively just tried to say `test1 = ??? + packetSize`).

To write to a variable without making it local, add either:

```
global test1
```

or

```
nonlocal test1
```

as the first line in your function. [The former explicitly jumps to global scope](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#global), [the latter looks for it in the nearest enclosing scope](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#nonlocal) (in this case, they're equivalent).

Note that as a rule, code that requires a `global` statement is usually bad form; it's usually a clue that you should be using instances of a class with the function being a method on that class (where each instance can preserve its own state, instead of there being only a single, global state).

Comment: As I mentioned in comments of my original post:
https://imgur.com/a/wALtCCM

Comment: If you really want to use `global` (which is still a very bad idea) you'll have to create the variable outside of the function and put the `global` statement in the function.

Comment: @JędrzejKieruj: You put the `global` declaration at top level, *outside* the function (which does nothing; didn't think it was even legal to be honest); as I said in my answer, you need to make it the first line *in* your function.

Comment: Thank you, it helped.
I will remember that it's not recommended to use globals, but in my case it was quite necessary because I tried passing `test1` into nested function and it didn't work properly(https://thepacketgeek.com/scapy-sniffing-with-custom-actions-part-2/). If you'd have solution how to pass `test1` into `custom_action` like in attached link, I'd be really thankful.

Answer (score 3):

Python will allow you to read and modify variables in the global scope inside a function, but as soon as you **assign** a new value to it, it assigns in the local scope of the function instead. See https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value:

"*when you make an assignment to a variable in a scope, that variable becomes local to that scope and shadows any similarly named variable in the outer scope*".

To assign to the global scope instead, use the following line at the beginning of your function:

```
global test1
```